# Can I get the companies a user is admin of AND their picture urls via LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

Using LinkedIn API [Documentation for company pages](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages), I know how to retrieve  :

1. The [list of companies](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#list_companies) a user is admin of
2. Several [profile fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_profile) for each individual company

Can I do that in one call instead of N+1 calls ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up answering my own question pretty quickly. Calling the API in the following way gives you the list of companies AND the list of profile fields you need :

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies:(id,name,ticker,description,website-url,square-logo-url)?format=json&is-company-admin=true